# Can I add metadata while saving an image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, metadata, flutter-image

I want to add metadata ex: capture date, Latitude, longitude, etc to an image while saving it.

Is it possible? If so, how to do it? Any suggestion would be a big help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://pub.dev/packages/metadata/example)?

Comment: @tomerpacific I think this package is for extracting metadata. But I want to add metadata.